# changing audio track when a certain dom element enters viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a codepen that illustrates changing music depending on what is showing in the viewport:

http://codepen.io/littleredbowtie/pen/epONpM

One song is triggered by an element at the top and a different song is triggered when you scroll to the bottom. However, If you scroll from top to the middle and then back up to the top, the first song starts over. Since it is the SAME DOM element coming into the viewport, I do not want to reset the music. I have tried using a variable to track the most recently viewed trigger , for example:

```
var oldInview = "";
```

and only to change the music if it's different. But as you can see from the codepen, it doesn't work. What is a recommended solution?

Comment: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview - for others like me, this plugin is used in the codepen example.

Comment: the problem is you're checking the condition outside the event callback, fixed... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xmrdax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than wrap your `$('p.inview1').bind(...)` in an if, add `&& oldInview !== 'view1'` to your `if (visible)`. This makes sure nothing is called again if `oldInvew === 'view1'` despite the event being fired and detected.

```
$('p.inview1').on('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible && oldInview !== "view1"){
    $(this).text('Yay! You can see me1!');
    myFunctionT1();
    oldInview = "view1";
  } else {
    $(this).text('Hidden again. Muhahah!');
    myFunctionP1();
  }                
});
```

Comment: I just ended up creating the working codepen, but you answered it first!

Comment: thank you both. I was almost there. before my stupid solution I had tried -- if (visible) && (oldInview) != "view1" {   --   but obviously that is a syntax FAIL.